Is there a way to increase the line limit for JavaScript syntax highlighting in Visual Studio 2022?
The syntax highlighting has been working fine before but now after update to this Current Version 17.11.0 it seems to stop after 10000 lines. The same in all other JavaScript files.
I've tried to look for some settings in options but could not find one.

A fix was implemented in the latest release (17.12.0). I found the answer here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Javascript-Files-Lose-Color-Coding-after/10687814. You'll need to go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Advanced, and update "TextMate parser line limit (required restart)".

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Consider using extensions like "Syntax Highlighting Fixer" or "Large File Viewer" to handle large files better.

Thanks for these alternatives, but for now I had to rollback to Version 17.10.6. This problem has been under consideration by MS since Jun 20. in 17.11 Preview.
link
Unfortunately it's been carried over to the recent update.
